# Adding audio to a video file

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I'm trying to add a wav file as background to an mp4 video and have no idea where to start...I've tried looking in to the "Video Editor" API but found nothing useful...

Is it worth using ffmpeg in some form on device or is there a way I'm overlooking? (and if so are there any good tutorials for a noob?)

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes ffmpeg is good enough

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -i in.wav -acodec <give your codec> -vcodec copy out.mp4
```

should do the trick and works for me.

Comment: Excellent thanks! It has taken me a while just to compile the thing, now to figure out how to use them in my app (all I have are three folders for the various processors with stuff in and no idea what to do,I'm still very very new at this)...

Comment: Hey @user1504495 did you find solution for android of adding audio in video.Please help me in this issue.I'm stuck.many Thank Robin.