# Android encode a video starting from a set of images

Tags: android, video, encode

Any suggestion on how to encode a videoclip starting from a set of images in Android? I've tried JCodec but it is not documented and I was unable to use it. Any other alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think JCodec is properly documented. I had used it successfully in a project few days back. Download the sample app from the below link and you will get an idea.

[JCodec android sample project](http://jcodec.org/downloads/jcodec-samples-android-0.1.7.zip)

Comment: You are right... I finally managed in using JCodec. Do you know whether it is possible to add an audio trace with JCodec?

Comment: Not possible using JCodec...You might have to use other libraries

Comment: You can do it using `ffmpeg`..have a look at this question..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259713/adding-audio-to-a-video-file

Comment: But using `ffmpeg` in android is not that easy..you have to use `ndk`..not impossible though..most of the famous video and audio editing apps in android use `ffmpeg` for encoding!